# google chrome js console show thin red line, no printed error text

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

I'm getting some errors in javascript, but for some reason google chrome wont print the error but shows only a thin red line. 
Also strange that when the thin red line is displayed the console window scrolls up, but not to the very top of history.

Has anyone seen this before and is there something I can do to get the actual text of errors displayed?

[image]

UPDATE: looks that these messages are occurring as result of exceptions in promises. When I debug and step through `console.error(ex.message)` code it still prints it as a thin red line. Maybe something to do with a permission to use console from a promise thread?

running Google Chrome Version 65.0.3325.181 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: I'm seeing this as well, but my case doesn't appear to be related to promises.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem with the red line.  Ran the site in Firefox and was able to see the error.  In my case there were multiple errors happening in a forEach loop.  Looks like Chrome is trying to protect from blowing up the console from errors within a loop?

Firefox just displayed one error.  It seems they've found a more elegant way to report to the console.

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem too, fixed it by switching to [Chrome Canary](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html)

And here I thought Chrome Canary was the unstable build. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix; close and re-open your dev tools. That did it for me.